# How to destroy sess_cookie_name in codeigniter after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using sess_driver like this in config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'CISESSION';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

It is working after browser close means when i close the browser and again when i login it is inserting a new row to ci_sessions table  but its not happening after logout means if i logout and again do the login then it is not 
inserting a new row in ci_sessions table.

Kindly help .

Comment: `$this->session->sess_destroy();` on logout

Comment: i am using it and it is clearing all the session  but when i am doing login again then it is not inserting a new row to ci_sessions table means it is just updating the timestamp value.

Comment: i mean to say it should clear everything what it is happening after browser close like may be session cookie etc...

Comment: well if you `print_r($_SESSION)` after logout and it doesn't have any of your session variables previously set at login i wouldn't worry about it. if you mean to say that the previous row isn't deleting... well that makes sense as ci runs a garbage collector every once and a while to delete out of date sessions so the session in the db from previous login won't immediately disappear although it will be invalid.

Comment: No there is no issue with the previous row deleting , i mean to say that when i logout and login then it should generate a new row  with new id in ci_sessions table which is currently updating now .

Comment: i'm curious, but is this described behavior affecting your system? i.e. can a user who logged out access the 'restricted' sections?

Comment: User who logged out can not access  that is working fine .Actually i am trying to make how many time the user logged in  using codeigniter session  driver

Comment: Querying the sessions table seems like a bad approach. Better would be to increment a counter in the users table every time they login. Quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you are describing is the default behavior. Nevertheless, you could try:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
if (substr(CI_VERSION, 0, 1) == '2') {
    $this->session->sess_create();
} else {
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
        session_start();
    }
    $this->session->sess_regenerate(TRUE);
}
```

for logging out (taken from `Ion_Auth`)

Comment: then what you are experiencing is probably the default behavior.